# Starting graylog2 web interface

Tags: passenger, graylog2

I am running the following command to start my backend.

```
passenger start -e production
```

But I am getting this error:

```
*** ERROR ***
Could not start Passenger Nginx core:
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open()
"/var/folders/jb/ln9fjc350gj85ntzrhthxc_85ffn5t/T/passenger-standalone.190uy5z/l
ogs/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2013/07/24 12:22:47 [emerg] 24155#0: "passenger_pre_start" directive The primary
group of the user specified by the 'default_user' option does not exist. Your
system's user account database is probably broken, please fix it. in
/var/folders/jb/ln9fjc350gj85ntzrhthxc_85ffn5t/T/passenger-standalone.190uy5z/co
nfig:93
Stopping web server... done
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue with passenger and fixed.

Fix:
passenger uses 'nobody' as the default user and it takes the group which nobody is belongs to.

Change the default option with 'PassengerDefaultUser' directive in apache/nginx/httpd/virtual-host config.

```
PassengerDefaultUser your-user
```

Passenger will run the app with this 'you-user'

> 6.12.4. PassengerDefaultUser
>
> Phusion Passenger enables user switching support by default. This
>   configuration option allows one to specify the user that applications
>   must run as, if user switching fails or is disabled. This option may
>   only occur once, in the global server configuration. The default value
>   is nobody.
>
> 6.12.5. PassengerDefaultGroup
>
> Phusion Passenger enables user switching support by default. This
>   configuration option allows one to specify the group that applications
>   must run as, if user switching fails or is disabled. This option may
>   only occur once, in the global server configuration. The default value
>   is the primary group of the user specifified by PassengerDefaultUser.

**ERROR which i got**

> Passenger could not be initialized because of this error: The option
>   PassengerDefaultUser is set to 'nobody', but its primary group doesn't
>   exist. In other words, your system's user account database is broken.
>   Please fix it.